# simplify my multiline regex - match plus next x amount of lines

Tags: regex, haml

I have the following Haml code:

```
%ul#sub-nav
      %li.li1
        %a{:href => "/dsadasd/"} dasdasd
      %li.li2
        %a.selected{:href => "/asdadasd"} Tasdada /asdas
      %li.li3
        %a{:href => "/dasd/"} asdasd
      %li.li4
        %a{:href => "/wdasn/"} das
```

I seem to be able to match this with the following repetitive regex - `%ul#sub-nav\n.*\n^.*\n^.*\n^.*\n^.*\n^.*\n^.*\n^.*` in intellij's rubymine ide.

This looks way too repetitive. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `%ul#sub-nav` plus the eight following lines, this should do:

```
%ul#sub-nav(\n.*$){8}
```